# AngularJS: filter is firing many times, value is often undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Following snippet:

```
<h1>
    {{pid.pname}}
    <span style="font-size: 0.75em; text-shadow: none;">({{pid.pos}})</span>
    <span style="font-size: 0.5em; text-shadow: none;"><a ng-href="#/team/{{pid.team | the_link}}/">{{pid.group}}</a></span>
</h1>
```

Filter `the_link` defined like so...

```
myApp.filter('the_link', function() {
    return function(longname) {
        alert(longname);
        var parts = longname.split(' ');
        return parts[parts.length - 1].toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

The `alert()` call is fired several times on loading the page-- seemingly every time a `{{...}}` is parsed (4 times in the snippet), and it's undefined except for the one time where the `ngHref` is finally handled. Additionally, an `$interpolate:interr` is fired three of the four times...

Why is this? I think I'm misunderstanding a lifecycle of some kind. Any clarity appreciated.

Comment: can you add controller or pid object data structure

Comment: How is the pid value being set? Asyncronoously right? You should always keep a null check in your filter for the input because You filter will run every digest cycle and if the data is not available by that time you will get error during interpolation section which uses this filter. See http://plnkr.co/edit/jPx5LQ?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, async. I wrapped a `typeof(longname) != 'undefined'` around it and it seems to work. Not entirely grokking the binding but I get it. I'll read up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is mainly with the absence of null check in your filter. Your filter is going to run during every digest cycle, it could so happen that the interpolation directive when refreshes itself during a digest cycle you don't have value for `pid` or `pid.team` available yet. You might be trying to load it with an sync call (ex:- http, resource), so whenever your filter runs with `longname` undefined your filter will fail and you will see the error `$interpolate:interr` which is caught during the interpolation. To fix it, just add a null check in your filter:-

```
 return function(longname) {
       //You should always do a null check because data might not be available by the time the filter runs.

        if(!angular.isString(longname)) return;  //or just if(!longname) return;

        var parts = longname.split(' ') ;
        return (parts[parts.length - 1] || "").toLowerCase(); //Just to be safer
    }
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmVM2z?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Main reason can be you not defind team.

I have done same filter with following controller its working.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.pid={pname:'test', pos:'test pos',group:'f b c d',team:'A B C G T H J'};
```

}

See the demo [app](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/34/)

Also angularjs uses a 'dirty-check' approach, so it need to call all the filters to see if exists any change. After this it detect that have a change on one variable and then it execute all filters again to detect if has other changes. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs)

Comment: Well, in your example, why does the `alert()` fire three times given that there is only one anchor element?

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs